# Do any airports have a steeper standard approach than London City?

Tags: approach

Watching the CS100 certification of the 5.5deg steep [approach into London City](https://youtu.be/lXxiHrB9_FA?t=38), I wondered if there were any airports with steeper standard approaches. By standard I mean published.

[image]

I have seen [very steep non-standard approaches](https://youtu.be/278sbNRxn1I?t=47), but this is not the point of this question.

[image]

Comment: When I was living in Miami and had a relative typing flight plans for the FAA there, the airport at Tegucigalpa, Honduras, was notoriously the one where the passengers were most apt to be sharing an experience otherwise familiar only to dive bombers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm a bit late to the conversation, but I think I have a winner so far, at 9.61° for the KASE VOR/DME-C approach.

[image]

Comment: Great find, even if late to the game!

Answer (score 32):

I found the RNAV approach to [Steamboat Springs](https://skyvector.com/airport/SBS/Steamboat-Springs-Bob-Adams-Field-Airport) at **7.75°**

[image]

Comment: You win for steepest approach. Note, though, it only allows cat A and B aircraft.

Comment: @TomMcW True enough, so far. The runway is 450ft shorter than London City but it's the weight limit that is the disqualifier.

Comment: Wow that is a steep approach!

Answer (score 25):

I nominate [Sion, Switzerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sion_Airport) (LSGS).

The [IGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_landing_system#Variant) for runway 25 is **6°.** Here's the vertical profile of the [approach plate](https://www.sionaeroport.ch/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/AIP-LSGS-CHARTS-RELATED-TO-AN-AERODROME.pdf):

[image]

Another, ehem, published approach is the Space Shuttle's MLS runway 33 approach at Kennedy Space Center. **20°** when light:

[image]
([Source](https://airfactsjournal.com/files/2014/02/Shuttle-plate.jpg))

Comment: I like "prior permission required" :)

Comment: @IanF1: Also "missed approach n/a". :)

Comment: I think the 20° approach is only for gliders :)

Comment: Kudos for Kennedy originality, but not what I was thinking "standard" meant. I think the 3/95 publication date also slightly violates the FAA 56 day rule.)

Comment: @Pilothead - Sion still works ;)

Answer (score 25):

One of the steepest approaches within the CONUS is the LOC/DME approach to Aspen, CO, which has a final approach segment with a recommended approach glideslope of 6.59°.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

[Lugano LUG/LSZA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lugano_Airport) has an approach  of 6.65°.

[[image]][12]

Answer (score 10):

Just came back from a backpacking trip into Lake Placid KLKP, glide slope 7.92, and the relics of the olympic ski jumps looming a 1/2 mile to the S of the runway which are to be avoided on the missed approach....which we were.[image]